# Не получается отрисовать закрашенную прямоугольную область

Tags: java, opengl, opengles, lwjgl

Здесь я отправляю на отрисовку прямоугольную область с помощью `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);`, но на экране пустота, ничего не отрисовывает. 
Пробывал отрисовать линиями `glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 72);`, линиями все отрисовывает.

```
private void rectangleRender(MouseInput mouseInput) {
        glUseProgram(rectangleProgram);

        FloatBuffer vi = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        view.get(vi);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(rectangleProgram, "projectionMatrix"), false, pMatrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(rectangleProgram, "modelViewMatrix"), false, vi);
        glBindVertexArray(vaoRectangle);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rectangleBuffer);//pointbuffer-камера, точка помещаем ее в буффер
        if (startPointMouse != null && endPointMouse != null) {
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Rectangle.getRectangle(startPointMouse, endPointMouse), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        }
        if (!mouseInput.isRightButtonPressed()) {
            startPointMouse = null;
            endPointMouse = null;
        }
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(rectangleProgram, "c"), 0, 0, 1);//верхняя
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        if (rectangleBuffer > 2) {
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glBindVertexArray(vaoRectangle);
            glDeleteBuffers(rectangleBuffer);
            glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoRectangle);
        }
    }
```

**Вот формирование треугольников для прямоугольной области:**

```
public static FloatBuffer getRectangle(Vector3f dx, Vector3f dy) {
        prevX = dx.x;
        prevY = dx.y;
        curX =  dy.x;
        curY = dy.y;

        return BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3 * 72 * Float.BYTES).put(new float[]{
                //БЛИЖНЯЯ ПЛОСКОСТЬ
                prevX, prevY, zP, prevX, curY, zP,
                prevX, curY, zP,curX, prevY, zP,
                prevX, prevY, zP, curX, prevY, zP,

                prevX, curY, zP,curX, prevY, zP,
                curX, prevY, zP,curX,curY,zP,
                prevX,curY,zP,curX,curY,zP,
                //ДАЛЬНЯЯ ПЛОСКОСТЬ
                prevX, prevY, zC, prevX, curY, zC,
                prevX, curY, zC,curX, prevY, zC,
                prevX, prevY, zC, curX, prevY, zC,

                prevX, curY, zC,curX, prevY, zC,
                curX, prevY, zC,curX,curY,zC,
                prevX,curY,zC,curX,curY,zC,
                //ЛЕВАЯ ПЛОСКОСТЬ
                prevX, prevY, zP, prevX, curY, zP,
                prevX, curY, zP,prevX, prevY, zC,
                prevX, prevY, zP,prevX, prevY, zC,

                prevX, curY, zP,prevX, prevY, zC,
                prevX, prevY, zC,prevX, curY, zC,
                prevX, curY, zP,prevX,curY,zC,
                //ПРАВАЯ ПЛОСКОСТЬ
                curX,prevY,zP,curX,curY,zP,
                curX,curY,zP,curX,prevY,zC,
                curX,prevY,zP,curX,prevY,zC,

                curX,curY,zP,curX,prevY,zC,
                curX,prevY,zC,curX,curY,zC,
                curX,curY,zP,curX,curY,zC,
                //верхняя плоскость
                prevX,curY,zP,prevX,curY,zC,
                prevX,curY,zC,curX,curY,zP,
                curX,curY,zP,prevX,curY,zP,

                prevX,curY,zC,curX,curY,zP,
                curX,curY,zP,curX,curY,zC,
                curX,curY,zC,prevX,curY,zC,
                //нижняя плоскость
                prevX,prevY,zP,curX,prevY,zP,
                curX,prevY,zP,curX,prevY,zC,
                curX,prevY,zC,prevX,prevY,zP,

                curX,prevY,zC,prevX,prevY,zP,
                prevX,prevY,zP,prevX,prevY,zC,
                prevX,prevY,zC,curX,prevY,zC


        }).rewind();
    }
```

Comment: А отрисовка полигонов у вас двухсторонняя включена, или направление индексации с "по часовой" на "против часовой" меняли?

Comment: @Kromster есть места где я с через glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, aVbao.getSize(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); отрисовывал, но туда отправлял еще и индексы

Comment: @Kromster нормали треугольников наверное еще нужны?

Comment: Нормали нужны только для освещения. Для отрисовки - перечитайте мой камент выше еще раз (кажется вы его не поняли)

Comment: @Kromster я не особо разбираюсь в opengl) поэтому не знаю, может быть включено что-то:D

Comment: Значит просто проверьте отрисовку с вершинами в порядке 1-2-3-4-5-6 и в порядке 1-3-2-4-6-5 (то есть треугольники рисуются в другую сторону)